# Speech recognition word replacement

Tags: javascript, constants, speech-recognition

I am using speechRecognition and I would like to replace some spoken words to emoji's.

This is my code:

```
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';

let p = document.createElement('p');
const words = document.querySelector('.words');
words.appendChild(p);

recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {
  const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
    .map(result => result[0])
    .map(result => result.transcript)
    .join('');

    const poopScript = transcript.replace(/poop|poep|poo|shit|dump/gi, '');
    p.textContent = poopScript;
    
    const unicornScript = transcript.replace(/unicorn|eenhoorn/gi, '');
    p.textContent = unicornScript;

    if (e.results[0].isFinal) {
      p = document.createElement('p');
      words.appendChild(p);
    }
});

recognition.addEventListener('end', recognition.start);

recognition.start();
```

When you say 'unicorn', it prints the  emoji. But when I say poop, it just prints the word, not the emoji. If I turn the const around, it runs the poopScript but not the unicornScript

```
const unicornScript = transcript.replace(/unicorn|eenhoorn/gi, '');
p.textContent = unicornScript;

const poopScript = transcript.replace(/poop|poep|poo|shit|dump/gi, '');
p.textContent = poopScript;
```

I don't know why it doesn't run my second const.

Comment: I'll be happy if I never read the word poopScript again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `replace` statements are being executed, but you are throwing away the result of the first one.  You need to call the second `replace` method on the string from the result of the first `replace`.

```
var result = transcript.replace(/unicorn|eenhoorn/gi, '');
result = result.replace(/poop|poep|poo|shit|dump/gi, '');
p.textContent = result;
```

Or you can chain the calls together...

```
p.textContent = transcript
       .replace(/unicorn|eenhoorn/gi, '')
       .replace(/poop|poep|poo|shit|dump/gi, '')
       ;
```